# Is there a way to exclude language from URL in SXA Sitemap

Tags: sxa

We are using Sitecore SXA 1.7.1.

The checkbox '`Language Embedding`' is set to false for one of our SXA sites and all the site url's are rendering without language code. But, in the sitemap -provided by SXA- all the url's contain the language 'en' which we want to avoid.

We raised a Sitecore support ticket on this but didn't get any reponse yet. Is there a way to get this working in Sitemap as well?

**Update**:

```
protected virtual UrlOptions GetUrlOptions()
    {
      UrlOptions defaultUrlOptions = LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
      defaultUrlOptions.Site = this.Context.Site;
      defaultUrlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = false;
      defaultUrlOptions.SiteResolving = true;
      return defaultUrlOptions;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore has reported this as bug as suggested by @Gatogordo and provided fix for this https://sitecore.app.box.com/s/fzle8isub8ixogpsgfanhdiywifb5ype

Answer (score 2):

The sitemap generator uses these UrlOptions:

```
protected virtual UrlOptions GetUrlOptions()
{
  UrlOptions defaultUrlOptions = LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
  defaultUrlOptions.Site = this.Context.Site;
  defaultUrlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = false;
  defaultUrlOptions.SiteResolving = true;
  defaultUrlOptions.LanguageEmbedding = LanguageEmbedding.Always;
  return defaultUrlOptions;
}
```

The **LanguageEmbedding.Always** is causing your issue. This can be found in `Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.Sitemap.SitemapGenerator`.

I think it could be fixed as the Generator gets UrlOptions from the SitemapHandler that is calling it (without this hardcoded embedding) but that is an assumption.

Comment: I found attached decompiled code (updated in my question) where there is no code associated with LanguageEmbedding. Will it take by default as 'Always'

Comment: The code you found is in the handler. The code I gave you is from the generator that is used by the handler and there the embedding is hardcoded.

Comment: yeah, able to find out the code you mentioned. But, can we fix this through custom coding (like overriding the existing one). Already raised a ticket to Sitecore on this but still awaiting their response.

Comment: You could try to fix it yourself but I would give this info to Support and ask them for a fix.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If they are going to give a fix, will it be a new support dll?

Comment: Yes, the fix should include a support dll.

Comment: Sitecore has reported this as bug as suggested by @Gatogordo and provided fix for this https://sitecore.app.box.com/s/fzle8isub8ixogpsgfanhdiywifb5ype